# In Managed C++, what is the proper way to define a static singleton instance in a class?

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2015, managed, managed-c++

Jumping to Visual Studio 2015 from Visual Studio 2013, I've noticed some differences in how static self-instances in managed C++ classes are accepted by the compiler. Consider these two examples:

Method 1:

```
public ref class CResourceManager
{
public:
    static property CResourceManager^ Instance
    {
        CResourceManager^ get() { return %m_Instance; }
    }

private:
    static CResourceManager m_Instance;
};
```

Method 2:

```
public ref class CResourceManager
{
public:
    static property CResourceManager^ Instance
    {
        CResourceManager^ get() { return m_Instance; }
    }

private:
    static CResourceManager^ m_Instance = gcnew CResourceManager;
};
```

Method 1 used to work on 2013, but it's failing to compile on 2015. I unfortunately do not have the exact compiler error handy, but it was one of those "Missing semicolon before variable name" errors, basically saying it couldn't find the type `CResourceManager` (pointing to the static variable declaration).

So on to my questions:

1. Is method 1 supposed to work or be valid in managed C++?
2. Why would the second method work in 2015, but not the first (i.e. what are the differences)?
3. Which method is the proper way to accomplish the end goal?

Comment: Your snippets don't help us help you, it works fine in VS2015 as well.  Pretending that a reference class is a value is a so-so feature of the C++/CLI compiler that makes it very easy to write bad code or invoke very confuzzling error messages.  Just best not to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method 2 is the proper way to do it. The code you have listed is the equivalent of the C# idiom.

Method 1 is a bit unusual.

- The lack of a `^` on a declaration would normally mean that the variable is not allocated on the managed heap. However, since it's a static class member, I'm not sure where it actually gets created.
- `%` is normally used for declaring tracking references, the equivalent of passing a variable by `ref` or `out` in C#. To be honest, I didn't think that applying `%` to a variable without either `^` or `%` and taking the result as a `^` was even valid. (Though considering the 2015 compiler rejects it, it may not be.)

Even if Method 1 is valid, I'd still go with Method 2: The storage location of `m_Instance` and how it's returned are both plain, common, and easy to understand. This beats having to think about how the code works any day.

Comment: The lack of a ^ is actually just syntactic sugar in managed C++.  The object is still allocated on the heap.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/cpp-stack-semantics-for-reference-types (for however long MS decides to keep that link working...)